# GetFiles returns blank .Name attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to populate a ddl with file names that I get from a search on a shared folder and all sub-folders. 
All works fine but the .Name returns blank.

```cs
public JsonResult GetFiles(string MCodeID)
        {
            if (MCodeID == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(MCodeID));
            }

            List<Files> filelist = new List<Files>();
            //Searching Files in //192.168.1.191
            string path = @"\\192.168.1.191\Materials Project\";
            string searchPattern = MCodeID + "*";
            //string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            DirectoryInfo fi = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            int FCodeID = 0;
            foreach (var file in fi.GetFiles(searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                filelist.Add(new Files
                {
                    FCodeID = FCodeID,
                    FDescr = fi.Name
                });
                FCodeID += 1;
            }
            filelist.Insert(0, new Files { FCodeID = 0, FDescr = "--Select File--" });
            return Json(new SelectList(filelist, "FCodeID", "FDescr"));
}
```

The filelist has 2 set of values but the FDescr in both sets are blank. 
I would appreciate any help,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that `fi` is a `DirectoryInfo` object. For some reason, `Name` returns an empty string when the path is a UNC path ending with a backslash, and (at first sight) there also seems to be a difference in behaviour when comparing .NET Core with .NET Framework here. I won't dive any further in the code to find out why, since you probably want the file name there, not the directory name.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment, instead of `FDescr = fi.Name` you probably meant to use `FDescr = file.Name`

Comment: Thanks @Stijn, that was it.
I'm very new to .NET Core and .NET Framework and I would find that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answered by @Stijn**

```cs
public JsonResult GetFiles(string MCodeID)
        {
            if (MCodeID == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(MCodeID));
            }

            List<Files> filelist = new List<Files>();
            //Searching Files in //192.168.1.191
            string path = @"\\192.168.1.191\Materials Project\";
            string searchPattern = MCodeID + "*";
            //string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            DirectoryInfo fi = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            int FCodeID = 0;
            foreach (var file in fi.GetFiles(searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                filelist.Add(new Files
                {
                    FCodeID = FCodeID,
                    FDescr = file.Name
                });
                FCodeID += 1;
            }
            filelist.Insert(0, new Files { FCodeID = 0, FDescr = "--Select File--" });
            return Json(new SelectList(filelist, "FCodeID", "FDescr"));
}
```